# Error with Event Subscriber using getRouteName()

Tags: routes, event-subscribers

I have a problem with event subscriber. Here is the error:

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>   Error: Call to a member function getRouteName() on null in
>   Drupal\hello_world\EventSubscriber\HelloWorldRedirectSubscriber->onRequest()
>   (line 58 of
>   modules\custom\src\EventSubscriber\HelloWorldRedirectSubscriber.php).

and my code is:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\hello_world\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
//use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\currentRouteMatch;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\LocalRedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Drupal\Core\Url;


/**
 * Subscribers to the Kernel Request event and redirects to the
 * homepage when the user has the "non_grata" role.
 */
class HelloWorldRedirectSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   *  @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser; // Store the current user as a class property

  /**
   * HelloWorldRedirectSubscriber constructor.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $currentUser
   */
  public function __construct(AccountProxyInterface $currentUser) {
    $this->currentUser = $currentUser;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // $events['kernel.request'][] = ['onRequest', 0];
    // più elegante:
    $events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['onRequest', 0];
    return $events;
  }

  /**
   * Handler for the kernel request event.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent $event
   */

  public function onRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    //$request = $event->getRequest();
    //$path = $request->getPathInfo();
    // if ($path !== '/hello')
    // {
    //   return;
    // } BEST PRACTICE FOR KEEP DYNAMICITY: currentRouteMatch Service
    $route_name = $this->currentRouteMatch->getRouteName();

    // check against the route name (and not path name)
    if ($route_name !== 'hello_world.hello')
    {
      return;
    }

    $roles = $this->currentUser->getRoles();

    if (in_array('inaccettabile', $roles)) {
      // $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('/'));
      $url = Url::fromUri('internal:/');
      // LocalRedirectResponse class redirect the user to a local (safe) path
      $event->setResponse(new LocalRedirectResponse($url->toString()));
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out what could be the problem. :\

Comment: The error tells you the issue, "Call to a member function getRouteName() on null" and you're doing getRouteName() on $this->currentRouteMatch which doesn't exist (the erroe says its null). Take a look at this (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21tests%21modules%21theme_test%21src%21EventSubscriber%21ThemeTestSubscriber.php/class/ThemeTestSubscriber/8.2.x) and click the "view source" to see an example and see that they are doing with "currentRouteMatch"

Answer (score 1):

An event subscriber is just a service tagged with `name: event_subscriber` and implemented by a class implementing the [`EventSubscriberInterface`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21event-dispatcher%21EventSubscriberInterface.php/interface/EventSubscriberInterface/8.8.x) interface.

The code you are using is supposed to use a service, but the reference to that service isn't defined as parameter of the class constructor, nor it is initialized in any way.

The [`MainContentViewSubscriber`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21EventSubscriber%21MainContentViewSubscriber.php/class/MainContentViewSubscriber/8.8.x) class is an example of event subscriber implementation that uses the [*current_route_match*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/current_route_match/8.8.x) service. The key parts of that event subscriber (the [*main_content_view_subscriber*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/main_content_view_subscriber/8.8.x) service) are:

- The service definition

  ```
  class: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber
  arguments:
    - '@class_resolver'
    - '@current_route_match'
    - '%main_content_renderers%'
  tags:
    - { name: event_subscriber }
  ```
- The constructor of the `MainContentViewSubscriber` class

  ```
  public function __construct(ClassResolverInterface $class_resolver, RouteMatchInterface $route_match, array $main_content_renderers) {
    $this->classResolver = $class_resolver;
    $this->routeMatch = $route_match;
    $this->mainContentRenderers = $main_content_renderers;
  }
  ```

The *current_route_match* service is defined as argument of the event subscriber service, and it's defined as parameter of constructor of the event subscriber class.

Your event subscriber service/class needs to do the same. Of course, the other services used from the class I used as example aren't required in your case, so they can be omitted.

Comment: my service.yml is: 

hello_world.redirect_subscriber:
    class: \Drupal\hello_world\EventSubscriber\HelloWorldRedirectSubscriber
    arguments: ['@current_user']
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }

The problem is that I have read that code on a book so I dunno why it doesn't work..

Comment: The service arguments should be `['@current_user', '@current_route_match']`, the constructor arguments should be `$currentUser, $currentMatch`, and the constructor should assign those values to two properties (`$this->currentUser = $currentUser; $this->currentMatch = $currentMatch;`). (The class should then define a new property.)